# python data structure, what are the different and most often used ways to manipulate a list

Tags: python, list

I'm quite confused about the use of methods to manipulate a list in python. Say you have

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist.append(5) #works fine,
```

but when I put

```
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)

print adding(mylist) #will print out the orginal list without the 5.
```

Also,

```
data2 = data3 = [1,2,3]
data2 = data2 +[4]+[5]+[6] # doesn't works
data3 += [4] +[5] +[6] #works
```

But I'm quite confused how they work.

So I want to make a list(not in terms of python) of different ways to manipulate a list. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should check each of your examples in isolation. For example, `print adding(mylist)` should actually print `None`, because `adding()` doesn't return a value. You might be printing `mylist` somewehere else and getting confused.

Comment: Also, we would need to know what `data2` and `data3` are to understand why they do or don't work.

Comment: I think your examples pasted here is not what you actually meant. I've guessed what you *actually* meant in my answer and tried to explain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason you expect the original code to work is because you are
more familiar with passing by references in languages like C++. It is important
then to be aware of the difference of *pass by reference* and *pass by value*.
It is even more important to understand which one Python is using.

In short, Python actually uses neither *pass by reference* or *pass by value*;
passing is done via *object* in Python.

---

Long answer:

An example of *pass by value* can be made with C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void adding(int i) {
    i = i + 1;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    adding(i);
    printf("i is %d\n", i);  // will print "i is 0"
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the value of i is *copied* when passed to `adding()`. the `int i` inside
`adding(int i)` resides in a different memory location than the original `int
i` inside `main()`. So inside `adding()`, `i = i + 1` only affects the value in
the chunk of memory known only inside the scope of `adding()`, the `i` in
`main()` is totally unaffected because it resides in a different chunk of
memory.

An example of *pass by reference* can be made with C++:

```
#include <iostream>

void adding(int &i) {
    i = i + 1;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    adding(i);
    std::cout << "i is " << i << std::endl;  // will print "i is 1"
    return 0;
}
```

Here `i` is passed by reference to `adding()`. The `i` inside `adding()` refers
to exactly the same chunk of memory as the `i` in `main()`. And hence, `i` will
be incremented to 1.

---

Now, let's talk about Python by going back to your example (that I modified
by guessing what you actually meant =]):

```
# Case 1
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist.append(5)  # will print [1,2,3,4,5]

# Case 2
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)

adding(mylist)
print mylist  # will print [1,2,3,4,5]

# Case 3
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
def adding(mylist):
    mylist = mylist + [5]

adding(mylist)
print mylist  # will print [1,2,3,4]

# Case 4
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
def adding(mylist):
    mylist += [5]

adding(mylist)
print mylist  # will print [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Here, `mylist` is passed neither by value or reference. It is in fact passed by
object.

In Python, `mylist = [1,2,3,4]` creates a list `[1,2,3,4]` and attach a
[*tag*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)
`mylist` to it. The important thing here to note is that list is an
**object** (IIRC, every object is a [`PyObject`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#PyObject) or an extension to it).

Understand this distinction will enable you to make sense of the outputs in the
example cases:

1. In **Case 1**, `.append()` is called on `[1,2,3,4]` list object directly to
   alter the list value, and hence the object `myobject` is attaching to has
   changed. Notice that this is possible also because lists are mutable objects in
   Python.
2. In **Case 2**, `mylist` is NOT copied on passing to `adding()`, it is still
   "attached" to the same list object, similar to **Case 1**. Hence, calling
   `.append()` on this object *will* alter the object itself. Outside of
   `adding()`, since `mylist` still attaches to the same object (even though the
   object has altered itself), we get the output [1,2,3,4,5].
3. In **Case 3**, inside `adding()`, the local variable `mylist` is attached to
   a new object created by `[1,2,3,4]+[4]`. But the object the original `mylist`
   is pointing to has never been altered, therefore, the output remains to be
   `[1,2,3,4]`.
4. **Case 4** is a bit tricky. In Python lists are mutable, `+=` acts
   as a shortcut like `.extend()`, which acts on the calling object itself. Hence,
   the original object has been modified to `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `mylist` still
   attaches to it. It is perhaps also worth noting that for immutable objects like
   tuples, strings and numbers, `+=` will create a *new* object and attach the
   variable to it.

---

As for different ways to use lists in Python, this [**article written by Fredrik Lundh**](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) contains very thorough information.

Answer (score 2):

```
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)

print adding(mylist)
```

Your `adding` method doesn't return anything..

Add a `return mylist` after the `mylist.append(5)` in your `adding` method like this: -

```
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)
    return mylist
print adding(mylist)
```

Or you can just replace `print adding()` with this code(If you are not returning anything):-

```
adding(mylist)
print mylist
```

And, for your second problem: -

```
>>> data2 = data3 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> data2 = data2 + [1] + [2] + [3]
>>> print data2
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
>>> data3 += [1] + [2] + [3]
>>> print data3
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Actually for me, both of them works.. And it should work, what is the output you are getting?? (Specially, What are you expecting your output to be??)

Answer (score 1):

print `adding(mylist)` should print `None` since you are not returning anything from the function `adding()`.

The following:

```
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)

test_list = range(5)

print adding(test_list)

print test_list

adding(test_list)

print test_list
```

produces this output:

```
None
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Can you be more specific about your second example? What is data2 originally? What do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
def adding(mylist):
    mylist.append(5)

print adding(mylist)
```

There is no return statement.

```
print mylist
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This will print [1,2,3,4,5], since its pass by reference.. So your mylist will be modified even if you have not returned the list.

```
data2 = data3 = [1,2,3]
data2 = data2 +[4]+[5]+[6] #Actually works
```

Comment: It is strictly speaking not **passing by reference**, but passing by **objects**.